# How to handle POST requests using JQuery .load(this.href)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is building from my previous question located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896641/load-a-php-file-into-a-div-using-jquery)

I have a form (tsconfig.php) load into a div using .load(this.href) which posts the results to itself, however the form reloads the entire page and displays tsconfig.php rather than placing the output into the div.  How can I resolve this so that the output is displayed in place of the form?

P.S. Before you look ahead, I realize that some of the code is quite a mess and is probably not the best approach; it's code from an old script I'm trying to port across into a revamped script and I'm by no means experienced.  I'm learning by doing.

The link is:

```
<li><a class="ajax-link" href="/includes/scripts/tsconfig.php">TSConfig</a></li>
```

The script is:

```
<div class="grid_3" id="main_content">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("a.ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#main_content").load(this.href);
            });
        });
    </script>

</div>
```

The form tsconfig.php is:

```
<?php include("output_scripts.php"); ?>
<h4>TSConfig</h4>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="width:99%">
                <label>InstallShield Version</label><br />
                    <select name="isVersion" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlVersion\',\'\')', 0)" id="isVersion" class="box">
                        <option selected="2012Spring" value="2012Spring">2012 Spring</option>
                        <option value="2012">2012</option>
                        <option value="2011">2011</option>
                        <option value="2010">2010</option>
                        <option value="2009">2009</option>
                        <option value="2009 Express">2009 Express</option>
                        <option value="IS2008">2008</option>
                        <option value="IS 2008 Express">2008 Express</option>
                    </select>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="width:99%">

                            <input type="checkbox" name="no_internet" value="no_internet"> no_internet
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="width:99%">

                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if ($isVersion == "IS2008" && empty($_POST['no_internet']) || $isVersion == "IS 2008 Express"  && empty($_POST['no_internet']))
            {
                echo $output_macrovision;
            }
            elseif ($isVersion == "IS2008" && isset($_POST['no_internet']) || $isVersion == "IS 2008 Express" && isset($_POST['no_internet']))
            {
                echo $output_macrovision_no_internet;
            }
            elseif (isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($_POST['no_internet']))
            {
                echo $output_script;
            }
            elseif (isset($_POST['no_internet']))
            {
                echo $output_script_no_internet;
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you don't want to reload the whole page when submitting the form. You'll either have to use an iframe to load the form OR submit the form with an ajax request.

Comment: What's the function to do it with an ajax request?  Many thanks.

Comment: @DaveMelia it's $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you that you do not catch the event at all if the preventDefault doesn't work. If you want to be sure, place an alert in your event handler.

```
$("a.ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
    alert('Event handler was fired');
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main_content").load(this.href);
});
```

Edit: Also, use $.ajax() if you need to pass information to the server along with your request and $.load() if the server doesn't require any information to display the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the form submission with ajax so only the form will reload you could use something along these lines. This is a test page I whipped up that has the functionality you're looking for (*I think*)

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    print_r($_POST);
}
else
{
    ?>
    <form id="form_id">
        <input name="01" type="text" value="test1" />
        <input name="02" type="text" value="test2" />
        <input name="03" type="text" value="test3" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    <div id="main_content"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {

            $('body').on('submit', '#form_id', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    type: 'post'
                }).done(function(response) {
                    $('#main_content').html(response);
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I've used the `$('body')` jquery handle instead of `$('#form_id')`, because you're already loading the content dynamically with jQuery, and I believe (not fully tested) that events don't work with standard notation when content is loaded like this. Therefore the event needs to be handled on the `body`, and then the `#form_id`.

Comment: many thanks for this -- It sort of works because the whole page doesn't reload anymore, however the output isn't being displayed.  I'll add an answer containing the code I've used based on yours.

Comment: You need to change where I've written `url: "test.php"` to use the url of the form you're submitting to, then it should work.

Comment: You also look like you need to include jQuery in your example below, unless you're doing it elsewhere.

Comment: Hah, coulda sworn I changed that -- It didn't work, however. `            $(function() {
                $("a.ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#main_content").load(this.href);
                });
            });`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include("output_scripts.php"); ?>

<?php
if ($_POST) {
    print_r($_POST);
} else {
?>

<form id="form_id">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="width:99%">
                <label>InstallShield Version</label><br />
                <select name="isVersion" id="isVersion" class="box">
                    <option selected="2012Spring" value="2012Spring">2012 Spring</option>
                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
                    <option value="2011">2011</option>
                    <option value="2010">2010</option>
                    <option value="2009">2009</option>
                    <option value="2009 Express">2009 Express</option>
                    <option value="IS2008">2008</option>
                    <option value="IS 2008 Express">2008 Express</option>
                </select>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="width:99%">
                        <br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="no_internet" value="no_internet"> no_internet
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="width:99%">
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if ($isVersion == "IS2008" && empty($_POST['no_internet']) || $isVersion == "IS 2008 Express"  && empty($_POST['no_internet']))
        {
            echo $output_macrovision;
        }
        elseif ($isVersion == "IS2008" && isset($_POST['no_internet']) || $isVersion == "IS 2008 Express" && isset($_POST['no_internet']))
        {
            echo $output_macrovision_no_internet;
        }
        elseif (isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($_POST['no_internet']))
        {
            echo $output_script;
        }
        elseif (isset($_POST['no_internet']))
        {
            echo $output_script_no_internet;
        }
    }
    ?>

    <script>
        $(function() {

            $('body').on('submit', '#form_id', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    type: 'post'
                }).done(function(response) {
                        $('#main_content').html(response);
                    });
            });

        });
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```